# What are the implementation details for the react-bootstrap-typeahead cache?

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

I am working in an application where we use the AsyncTypeahead component from react-bootstrap-typeahead. It works wonderfully and I love the library, but recently I was tasked with auto-selecting the top result if a user types something then clicks outside of the field (so onBlur). I added my logic and during testing noticed that our search function was not always being called as I entered test data into the field.

After reading the docs, I found the useCache flag and realized it was defaulted to on, which is why we weren't always calling search. Toggling this to false ensures we call our search in all cases, and my auto-select is working seamlessly (I do some validation for auto-select on data that is set in our search function, which is why the two events are tied together in this case).

Before I push my changes out to prod I was hoping to get some info about the details of how this cache works and when we decide that the cache is no longer "valid", and a new search must be made. I basically am looking to understand the impact of disabling this cache, and I don't see anything specific in the docs.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

React-bootstrap-typeahead is open source, so you are free to take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/src/behaviors/async.js) if you'd like to understand the implementation. The built-in cache is very basic: it's just a plain object that adds key/value pairs corresponding to the query string and results. Before the search is triggered, the component checks the object to see if the current query has already been sent and if it has, will return the cached result.

Below are the relevant portions:

```js
const cacheRef: { current: Cache } = useRef({});
const queryRef: { current: string } = useRef(props.defaultInputValue || '');

const handleSearch = useCallback((query: string) => {
  queryRef.current = query;

  if (useCache && cacheRef.current[query]) {
    forceUpdate();
    return;
  }

  onSearch(query);
}, [forceUpdate, minLength, onSearch, useCache]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!isLoading && prevProps && prevProps.isLoading && useCache) {
    cacheRef.current[queryRef.current] = options;
  }
});
```

Comment: This is great! I was having trouble finding where the cache was implemented and hoped you'd find this question. I will review this as well as the code and go from there. Thank you!

Edit: it doesn't seem like there is any time or size constraint placed on the cache, which is good to know. Is there any logic/process around clearing this cache? Or does it clear during the onBlur event?